# XmlSlurper NodeChild that represents a body tag?

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I would like to get a Groovy NodeChild that represents, e.g., a body tag.

However, if I do

```
html=new XmlSlurper().parseText(blah)
```

I get html which is a NodeChild.

However html.body is a NodeChildren tag, and I can't seem to get a NodeChild.

Much help appreciated!

Thank you
Misha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but there must be something simpler:

```
def body=html.children().find { it.name()=="BODY" }
```

Misha

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def body = html.body.'**'
```

From there you can query the rest of your dom tree:

```
def myDiv = body.find { it.@id.text() == "divId" }
```

You can check it by printing out the result

```
println myDiv.'@id'.text()
```